# Custom UITableViewController doesn't load static cells

Tags: cocoa

I was experimenting with static cells, therefore I made a Table View and embedded a `UITableViewController` in it and then added some static cells. Everything worked fine until I made a new `UITableViewController` class and connected it as a custom class thorugh the interface builder. Since then, when I build the App, it just shows an empty Tableview without any cells in it and now I'm wondering what I'm missing.

I tried some researching, I doubt I'll be the first one to ask, but evidently I must have been looking for the wrong thing. I guess there must be something that goes to `ViewDidLoad`, so the static cells get loaded?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Remove the following methods from the .m file:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the template `UITableViewController`, it probably created a lot of skeleton `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods for you. When you're using a Storyboard with static cells, you should not implement these methods; simply delete them from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

What Hans said.
In addition make sure if you subclassed UITableViewController that those methods are removed from that aswell.